# Autocomplete using jQuery callback (label/value pair)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, callback

I am trying to implement autocomplete jQuery, but am not understanding the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) function that jQuery UI provides.

It uses a callback function and gets the response as a label/value pair. I have some sample code where I am trying to pass an arbitrary label/value pair back and display that option but it isn't working. If someone can help me out with that or show me a simple program it will be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/kB25J/

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
      Please enter your country name
      <input id ="book" type="text" value="">
    </body>
</html>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#book").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        alert(request.term);
        response(function() {
            return {
                label: "hi",
                value: "bye"
            }
        });
        alert(reponse);
    }
});
```

​
Thank You

Comment: <body>
  <input id ="book" type="text" value="">Please enter your country name</input>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#book").autocomplete({
           source: function(request, response){
      alert(request.term);
      response(function() {
       return {
       label:"hi", value:"bye"
       }
       });
       alert(reponse);

    }
        });
</script>

Comment: I added your code from the comments. You can edit your post to add any relevant code instead of adding the code in the comments :)

Comment: Hi Francois Thank you I wasnt able to indent the code

Comment: Who ever edited the code out before, leave it in as well as the fiddle in case the fiddle link goes stale so the question is usefull to tohers in the future. Thanks Mr Fooz for adding it back in.

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that

Comment: Sorry @FrançoisWahl I think we were editing at the same time. Thanks Mr Fooz for fixing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When sending response, pass an array instead of function.

```
$(function() {
    $("#book").autocomplete({        
        source: function(request, response) {
            var data = [{
                    label: "hi",
                    value: "bye"
                    }];
            response(data);
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#book" ).val( ui.item.label); //ui.item is your object from the array
            return false;
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Hi Prashanth The code works but what is response(data) supposed to do ?

Comment: 'response' is the callback function that you get to call with your data as parameter. response() expects an array as parameter. this array could either be a simple array (like ['a','b']) or array of objects each with 'label' and 'value' properties (like [{label:'VA',value:'Virginia'},{label:'CA',value:'California'}])

Comment: Hi Prashanth Will this display a drop down next to my text box with the suggestions in this case "hi"?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/kB25J/3/. When you start typing it will display the elements from the data array received from the response.

Comment: Hi Prashanth Thank You It worked !!! Just one more thing can u tell me if I cal make the value be displayed in the drop down instead of the label coz now it displays the label and sets the value. I want to dsiplay only one of the two in both cases. (ie on the drop down as well as the text box) Thank You

Comment: You need to use select event for that. Please check the modified code above. Check this for an interesting sample http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: Hi Prashanth Thank You the code works took me while to figure it out, but then now the problem is that if I enter H I am saying "too many results enter another character" so now when I type O after H the drop down does not refresh can you tell me how to fix it or show me on the above  example how they are achieving it  jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmikanthanv/3bUtD/ Hi Prashanth here is the fiddle I have only the Js code , In this case if I type h to promts both Hill and Hulu but when I type I after the H ie(Hi) it still shows both results basically hte select div doent refresh

Comment: you can simply do something like this for your case. but if you use src:function then you can filter manually inside (request.term is your key)

Comment: You mean I have to do the second time filtering by myself?

Comment: My response data 1 comes from the servlet usually and each tim eit is a different value I checked that just that the drop down div does not get refreshed with the new data

Answer (score 4):

You should be returning an array in your source even if its just 1 match in this case 'hi'/'bye'

As seen in this example on jqueryui.com

```
response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
    return {
        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
        value: item.name
    }
}));
```

Its returning an array of key/value pairs for label/value using a map on the remote response.

If your source is just a list of countries you can just use an array of strings as your source.

```
var countries = ["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", ...]

$('input').autocomplete({
    source : countries
});
```

If you are working with a remote source:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source : function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url_to_get_countries",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.countries, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.country_name,
                value: item.country_id
            }
            }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mark Can you give me some code, like I said I am not really getting the way autocomplete works from the description on the j query site. also please tell me if the div that is generated with the suggestions be genrated automatically?

Comment: @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan Are you working with a remote data source? Where are you getting your list from for the autocomplete, I can show you an example with whatever data source you're working with.

Comment: Hi Mark I am gonna do autocpmlete for countries I guess the db cannot be accessed from here. actually I am trying to get country names and a corresponding id using a label value pair

Comment: It would just work if it was an array of strings. @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan updated my answer to show an example with using an array of strings.

Comment: Yeah I got this part of it, but I need to get it from the database using an ajax call and also I need to have an id associated with my country name that is why I am trying to use a label value pair and a callback function

Comment: @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan I added an example working with a remote data source, assuming you respond with JSON

Comment: Hi Prashanth Thank You the code works took me while to figure it out, but then now the problem is that if I enter H I am saying "too many results enter another character" so now when I type O after H the drop down does not refresh can you tell me how to fix it or show me on the above  example how they are achieving it

Answer (score 1):

@LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan

As you can see at [Autocomplete guide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), there are three ways to implement autocomplete with jquery plugin.

- Providing an array with the list of values
- Providing an array of objects whith pairs value/label
- Providing an url to get the object array

The first two options are for a fixed list of values. If you want to populate the autocomplete list dinamically, you have to implement the last one.

To do that, you have to specify an url to get the objects array. If you want to keep the label and the key hidden, you need to create an input type hidden and set his value too.

For example

```
$( "#book" ).autocomplete({
           source: "getValues.htm",                     
           select: function(event, ui) {  
                $( "#book" ).val(ui.item.label);  
                $( "#book_hidden" ).val(ui.item.value);
                return false;  
            }                           
        });
```

getValues.html must return the array of label/values pair.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Tux Is it possile for me to do the select thing with this example  jsfiddle.net/kB25J/3.

Comment: Hi, I've updated your code at http://jsfiddle.net/kB25J/4/. As you can see, i've defined data array outside autocomplete element. I think (but not sure) that if you define array of data into the autocomplete "source" option, everytime you are going to return whole array. I've included an input to store de value too, that is filled when you select an element. Remember that always you select the label, not the value. If you want to select the value, you have to change the "select" behavior. pd. Sorry, i didn't save the changes :(, i'm going to edit again :)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax , Key Value pair ,Min Length to trigger search. Simple Code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CompanySearch").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Admin/GetCompanyAutoComplete',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

For more

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40883309/5237614

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

@Edathadan
Your response is the best solution. But, I think we need to keep the origin request, so you should modify to:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CompanySearch").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Admin/GetCompanyAutoComplete?term=' + request.term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```