# parsing input field contents on blur using jquery and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

After a user has selected a value from an autocomplete list (Using jQuery autocomplete), I need to remove everything from the input box after the first space.

I got this far then got a bit lost. (currently just alerts on blur)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".pn-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: "pn-json.php",
            minLength: 2,
        }).blur(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the value? What means remove everything? The value itself? like: $(this).val('');?

Comment: after selecting "blah people foo bar" I want to only have "blah" remaining in the text box.

Comment: I would also be happy if someone could inform me how to easily pass two variables to jQuery autocomplete (One to display and One to store in the input field after selection)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219026/jquery-use-key-value-pair-in-autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eVJxy/)**

Check this code snippet - It would skip all the text after the first space.

```
$(function () {
    $( ".pn-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: "pn-json.php",
        minLength: 2,
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).val(function () {
            return this.value.split(' ')[0];
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for your example. It works fine in the demo, but when placed in the code, does not. I guess something is interfering in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value to the first word like this,

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".pn-autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: "pn-json.php",
            minLength: 2,
        }).blur(function () {
            var input_val = $(this).val(),
                first_word = input_val.replace(/(\w+).*/,"$1");
            $(this).val(first_word);
        });
    });
</script>
```