# jQuery UI Autocomplete in CodeIgniter displays value instead of label

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been following [this](http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/) tutorial to create autocomplete functionality in my form.I'm pretty new to codeigniter and jquery.
My table name is 'user_profile'
I want to autocomplete 'comp_person_name' and value should be 'p_u_id'.

here is my model

```
public function get_user($q){
    $this->db->select('comp_person_name,p_u_id');
    $this->db->like('comp_person_name', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('user_profile');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        // $row_set[]=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['comp_person_name']));
         $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['comp_person_name']));
         $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['p_u_id']));
        $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array

      }
      echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
      }
    }
```

and here is my controller

```
 public function get_users(){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->user_model->get_user($q);


            }
        }
```

and here is function call

```
$("#partners").autocomplete({
    source: "get_users" ,
     minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){            
            $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
        });
```

& Html code

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2  control-label">Referral partner </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">                                   
       <input type="text" id="partners"  name="assign_to" placeholder="Search    partner"  class="form-control"  />
      </div>
   </div>
```

Problem is when i press keys, it shows name of persons on dropdown and values on input form . How can i get name on input box also.See the pic below

[image]

Comment: can u provide your html code please?

Comment: @Gautam Sorry , added html

Comment: just use var_dump($query); see waht are results

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autocomplete applying value not label to textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642855/autocomplete-applying-value-not-label-to-textbox)

Comment: I found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219026/jquery-use-key-value-pair-in-autocomplete][1]

I think that resolve your problem.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219026/jquery-use-key-value-pair-in-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you @spenibus , That link helped

Answer (score 1):

I resolved myself with the help of [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642855/autocomplete-applying-value-not-label-to-textbox)

Edited Javascript to

```
$("#partners").autocomplete({
             source: "get_users",
             minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#partners").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#partners-hidden").val(ui.item.value);
            },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#partners").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#partners-hidden").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```

and added a hidden input field in html  with id #partners-hidden for storing and submitting value