# Autocomplete from array and get the corresponding id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

Just wondering if someone knows a way to be able to autocomplete an input field after you type 3 letters then also get the id of the corresponding value?

I tried something like this with the [UI Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/):
It works great with the test array, but not with the real array im trying to use. Is it because the format is wrong? I include the array before json_encode and after.

```
var test = ["1899 Hoffenheim vs Borussia Dortmund", "SD Eibar vs Granada CF", "Fiorentina vs AS Roma"];
var availableTags =  <?php echo json_encode($testArray); ?>;
console.log(availableTags);
    $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
    source: test
    });
});
```

**Before json_encode**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33820950
                [match] => 1899 Hoffenheim vs Borussia Dortmund
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33820951
                [match] => SD Eibar vs Granada CF
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33820952
                [match] => Fiorentina vs AS Roma
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33820991
                [match] => Hibernian vs Rangers
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33821044
                [match] => RKC Waalwijk vs FC Twente
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33821045
                [match] => Middlesbrough vs Stoke City
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33821108
                [match] => Deportivo La Coruña vs CD Tenerife
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33821138
                [match] => Zaglebie Lubin vs Legia Warszawa
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 34096342
                [match] => Everton vs Arsenal
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 34096343
                [match] => Aston Villa vs Southampton
            )

    )
```

**After json_encode**

```
[{"id":"33820950","match":"1899 Hoffenheim vs Borussia Dortmund"},{"id":"33820951","match":"SD Eibar vs Granada CF"},{"id":"33820952","match":"Fiorentina vs AS Roma"},{"id":"33820991","match":"Hibernian vs Rangers"},{"id":"33821044","match":"RKC Waalwijk vs FC Twente"},{"id":"33821045","match":"Middlesbrough vs Stoke City"},{"id":"33821108","match":"Deportivo La Coru\u00f1a vs CD Tenerife"},{"id":"33821138","match":"Zaglebie Lubin vs Legia Warszawa"},{"id":"34096342","match":"Everton vs Arsenal"},{"id":"34096343","match":"Aston Villa vs Southampton"}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Sorry, I misunderstood you at first. I guess you want to save all text values of the key `match` to a json array. So I take your `$testArray`, loop through it and assign everything to a new array that it matches the format.

Try this:

```
<?php
$array = [];
$i = 0;
$id = 0;
$ids = '[';
$availableTags = '[';
foreach($testArray as $val) {
   $id[] = "\"".$val[$i]['id']."\"";
   $array[] = "\"".$val[$i]['match']."\"";
   $i++;
}
$id = implode(', ', $id);
$array = implode(', ', $array);
$availableTags .= $array . '];';
$ids = $id . '];';
?>
var availableIds = <?= $ids; ?>
var availableTags = <?= $availableTags; ?>
console.log(availableTags);
    $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
    source: 
       return {
          label: availableTags,
          value: availableIds
       };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i'm getting GET 403 (Fobidden) error in the console.

Comment: Added the code now, no error but nothing is happening when i type in the input field.

Comment: The result of `echo $availableTags` after the php code is `[];` So the array does not get added

Comment: It worked when i did this `$test = '['.$array.'];';` But how do i get the associated id?

Comment: Like maybe the associated id get added to the value of the input field when the match is selected. Possible?

Comment: I see that you are using the Jquery autocomplete function, so to define the key and the label value you need to return both in an extra option block like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219026/jquery-use-key-value-pair-in-autocomplete

Comment: I updated it again. Does this updated code work now?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'`

Comment: Both arrays have the right output, it just the SyntaxError, trying many different things

Answer (score 0):

Finished working code. Where you can search for the match and both match and the  corresponding id gets saved.

```
  <form action="" method="POST" >
      <input id="match_search" name="match_search" onChange="this.form.submit()">
      <input id="match_id" name="match_id" hidden>
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['match_search'])) {
      $match = $_POST['match_search'];
      $match_id = $_POST['match_id'];
      echo $match.'<br>';
      echo $match_id;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
    var availableMatches = <?=json_encode($testArray); ?>;
    $(function() {
        $("#match_search").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: availableMatches,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#match_search').val(ui.item.label);
                $('#match_id').val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $("#match_search").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```